# Download Managers not taking correct title

Tags: php, html, download-manager

I have created a script that generates direct url to download a mp4 file.The problem is that download managers don't catch the correct title.

```
<a href="<?php echo $mp4_720p; ?>">"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
```

**$mp4_720p** --> the url of the mp4 file .This is dynamic and is unique for each downloader.

**$title**-->It is the name of the video file

The problem is that my download manager (IDM) recognise the file name as videoplayback.mp4  when i want it to be $title.mp4

Is there anything i am missing here in the html  ??

**UPDATE**
I found a nice html5 solution that works

```
<a href="<?php echo $mp4_720p; ?>" download="<?php echo $title; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
```

Browser takes the title as the filename as expected but unfortunately Download Managers are still unable to pick up the correct filename

Regards

Comment: is your php script doing `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$title.mp4'");` ?

Comment: Just to exclude the obvious: can't you rename your file from `videoplayback.mp4` to `$title.mp4`?

Comment: @ AD7six Nope i am not sending any Content-Disposition header in my script atm.

Comment: @Carsten i can't rename since the link generated is not from my server @

Comment: Then yoy can't do what you ask - especially since the file isn't on your sever. The title of a link pointing at a url has no bearing at all on what the downloaded file (if the link triggers a download) is called.

Comment: Please check **UPDATE ** guys i found a partial html5 solution